# Is it possible to deploy a new application which will overwrite an existing application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I have an outdate software deployed on a network location, `Software A`. I am in the process of rewriting it for performance, `Software B`. Is it possible to deploy `Software B` in a way so that when user opens the existing `Software A` it prompts for an update and installs `Software B`? Both projects are separate projects hosted in a single solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to just copy all the files from `Software B` to `Software A` and publish `software A`